# Is it necessary to use personal pronoun with whatever, whoever etc. everytime?

Tags: personal-pronouns

Consider the following sentences:
1. Whatever you give, I'll eat.
2. Whatever you give, will be eaten.
Now consider this:
3.a) Whatever happens, happens for good.
3.b) Whatever happens, it happens for good.

4.a) Whoever comes first, will be talked politely to.
4.b) Whoever comes first, he will be talked politely to.

1 and 2 seem to be correct, but when it comes to 3 and 4, which of the parts are correct? I

Comment: There should be no commas in (2) and (4a).  (3b) is at best clumsy.  // '... talked to politely' sounds far more natural.

Comment: Does hidden subject also qualify for independent clause? Example:  "will go" for "he will go"

Comment: In 'Whoever comes first will be talked to politely.' the subject is 'Whoever comes first' and the whole sentence is an independent clause.

Comment: Oh, thanks sir! 4.b is superfluous, you agree? Shouldn't be there a universal rule because many people do use 4.b?

Comment: It's not incorrect, just rather unwieldy in usual conversation. However, there are times that I might choose it myself to add emphasis, depending on prior context.